# Show that $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}+(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x})\mathbf{c}$ has a unique solution provided that $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} \neq 1$

Tags: vectors

I am trying to show that the equation
$$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{a}+(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x})\mathbf{c}
$$
has a unique solution $\mathbf{x}$ provided $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} \neq 1$. Thus far, all I have is the following;
$$
\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}+(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x})(\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{b}) \implies (1-\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c})(\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{b}) = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}
$$
And since $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} \neq 1$, I have that $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \frac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}}{1-\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}}$
I'm not really sure where to go from here or if this is helpful in the first place. I thought of maybe constructing a new basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I don't know what basis vectors to use. Also, in the case when $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}=1$, clearly then $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}=0$, so $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are orthogonal, but I don't know what other conclusions to draw about the number of solutions to the original equation.

Comment: Suppose there is another solution $\textbf{y} \not= \textbf{x}$. Find the difference $\textbf{y}-\textbf{x}$ and see if that leads to a contradiction under $\textbf{b} \cdot \textbf{c} \not= 1$. (I guess I should ask if you're running into issues with existence or with uniqueness.)

Comment: @BrianTung I'm running into issues with existence thus far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x}+(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x})(\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{b})$": is wrong. $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \color{red}{\mathbf{b}}+(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x})(\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{b})$. So,
"in the case when $b⋅c=1$, clearly then $a⋅x=0$
" is also wrong.

- If $c=0$, the solution is obvious.
- Assuming now $c\ne0$ but $b\cdot c\ne1$,
  $$\begin{align}x=a+(b\cdot x)c&\iff\exists k\in\Bbb R\begin{cases}x=a+kc\\k=b\cdot x\end{cases}\\&\iff\exists k\in\Bbb R\begin{cases}x=a+kc\\k=b\cdot a+kb\cdot c\end{cases}\\&\iff x=a+\frac{b\cdot a}{1-b\cdot c}c,
  \end{align}$$
  so that there is a unique solution.
- Finally, if $b\cdot c=1$,
  $$\begin{align}x=a+(b\cdot x)c&\iff\exists k\in\Bbb R\begin{cases}x=a+kc\\k=b\cdot x\end{cases}\\&\iff\exists k\in\Bbb R\begin{cases}x=a+kc\\b\cdot a=0\end{cases}\\&\iff \begin{cases}b\cdot a=0\\x\in a+\Bbb Rc,\end{cases}
  \end{align}$$
  so that the set of solutions is either $\varnothing$ (if $b\cdot a\ne0$), or an affine line (if $b\perp a$).

Comment: I see it now, thanks